# Modify example dropdown in memoir

Tags: environments, lyx, memoir, modules

In LyX, in `book` format `memoir`, the drop down has the `Example` format. Just wanted to know how do I change this `Example` format layout. Or where is the code to be changed.

Edit: 
The example might be coming because of the modules I have used. I have a snap of both the example shown in the drop down as well as the modules, if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this from withing Lyx or externally?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I see no "Example" in the drop down-menu on the top left.

Comment: thanks for ur comment that I thought of putting the snaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Example` environment stems from the module "Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type)" - defined in `theorems-ams-bytype.inc` - that you've included - :

```
    Style Example
        CopyStyle             Definition
        LatexName             example
        LabelString           "Example \theexample."
        Preamble
         \theoremstyle{definition}
          \newtheorem{example}{\protect\examplename}
        EndPreamble
        Requires              amsthm
        LangPreamble
          \providecommand{\examplename}{_(Example)}
        EndLangPreamble
        BabelPreamble
          \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\examplename}{_(Example)}}
        EndBabelPreamble
        LabelCounter          example
    End
```

Under Windows, this is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX20\Resources\layouts
```

The `example` counter used is defined in `theorems-ams-bytype.module`, located in the same folder. You'll need some understanding of LaTeX to modify this to your liking, including LyX' syntax.

Comment: Is it a way to use tikz decoration in the example.. ??